# IndexOutOfBoundsException error in android studio

Tags: java, android, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

I have build an application the code is right. Still  I am getting an error of

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 7, size is 7

whenever I am running app. Can't figure out what is the problem

I have checked many solution nothing helped me.

my code is

```
    public class Lecture extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_lecture);
    List<List<String>> arrayOfListsA= new ArrayList<List<String>>();

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences("MyData",MODE_PRIVATE);
    String username=sharedPreferences.getString("username","NA");
    String password=sharedPreferences.getString("password","NA");
    TextView av=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvavg);


    double sub=0,subt=0,prd=0,sec=0,btch=0,day=0,date=0;

    try {
        arrayOfListsA = new HttpGetLecture().execute(username,password).get();
        List<String> subject = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> subjecttype = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> period = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> section = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> batch = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> day1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> date1 = new ArrayList<String>();

        GridView gridView=(GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridLect1);
        subject = arrayOfListsA.get(1);
        subjecttype = arrayOfListsA.get(2);
        day1= arrayOfListsA.get(3);
        period= arrayOfListsA.get(4);
        date1= arrayOfListsA.get(5);
        section= arrayOfListsA.get(6);
        batch= arrayOfListsA.get(7);



        /*for(int i=0;i<subject.size();i++) {
            sub = sub + parseInt(subject.get(i));

        } */

           /* for(int j=0;j<subjecttype.size();j++){
            subt=subt+ parseInt(subjecttype.get(j));


        }
        for(int k=0;k<period.size();k++){
            prd=prd+ parseInt(period.get(k));
        }

        for(int l=0;l<section.size();l++){
            sec=sec+ parseInt(section.get(l));
        }

        for(int m=0;m<batch.size();m++){
            btch=btch+ parseInt(batch.get(m));
        }

        */
        //avg=  (out / per) * 100;
        //av.setText("Average Attendance :- "+ String.valueOf(avg)+" %");

        gridView.setAdapter(new CustomAdapterLecture(this,subject,subjecttype,period,section,batch,day1,date1));



    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        e.getMessage();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

Comment: size 7 means valid indices are from 0-6

Comment: What part of the error is unclear? You are trying to access past the boundaries. Have you debugged and checked what you get into your arrayOfListsA to see what's going on? Or did you just index starting from 1 and not 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The index starts at 0 not at 1, you should get wrong value anyway.
its a good idea toi write unitTest for things like that, in order to find your error early.

Answer (score 0):

Java array indexes start with 0 up to size-1 (inclusive).

You should fix your indexes accordingly:

subject = arrayOfListsA.get(1); 
should be 
subject = arrayOfListsA.get(0);
etc.

Answer (score 0):

replace this

```
 GridView gridView=(GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridLect1);
        subject = arrayOfListsA.get(1);
        subjecttype = arrayOfListsA.get(2);
        day1= arrayOfListsA.get(3);
        period= arrayOfListsA.get(4);
        date1= arrayOfListsA.get(5);
        section= arrayOfListsA.get(6);
        batch= arrayOfListsA.get(7);
```

With

```
 GridView gridView=(GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridLect1);
        subject = arrayOfListsA.get(0);
        subjecttype = arrayOfListsA.get(1);
        day1= arrayOfListsA.get(2);
        period= arrayOfListsA.get(3);
        date1= arrayOfListsA.get(4);
        section= arrayOfListsA.get(5);
        batch= arrayOfListsA.get(6);
```

As index start with 0 not 1